# How to set up multiple email targets for Post-commit notification in VisualSVNServer?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, svn-server

I am trying to set up multiple email targets for post-commit email notification.

I have tried comma separated emails including quotes and with separate quotes as below.

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
    commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
    --from "svn.server_zenforte@zensar.com" --to "hsalunkh@abcd.com","hrushikesh.salunkhe@abcd.com" ^
    --smtp-server javamail.abcd.com
```

Email notification should be sent to multiple email ids on commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

Turns out that mailing server I'm using will send emails only to mails with same domain name.